# First modal on each page not displaying data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a workstation assessment website.
I am stuck with an issue I am having.

The modal is my a grandchild component (modal complete questions). I then have a component named questions as a parent  and as the parent to that I have  Admin Workstations.

Hierachy 
1.AdminWorkstations,
2.Questions,
3.Modal,

(this is not full functionality of these components but is just for the use case I am asking for).

1.Parent gets WSAId(just a id).Passes down to questions.
2.Questions passes the modal component this. 
3.Modal gets questions using this id.

However the first modal does not display.I have paginated the results of these page if this makes any diffrence.

this is my modal

```
import "./ViewWorkstationModal.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Modal, DropdownButton, Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";


function ModalCompletedQuestions(props) {
  const [show, setShowState] = useState(0);
  const [loadingToken, setLoadingToken] = useState(0);
  const [answeredQuestions, setAnsweredQuestions] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoadingToken(true);
    let data = {
      WSAId: props.WSAId
    };
    fetch("/get-completed-questions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        setAnsweredQuestions(results.recordset);
      });
  }, []);

  function handleClose() {
    setShowState(false);
  }

  function handleShow() {
    setShowState(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <>
        <div className="header-container">
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary"
            style={{ float: "right" }}
            onClick={handleShow}
          >
            Response Overview
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Modal
            size="lg"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            show={show}
            onHide={handleClose}
            animation={true}
          >
            <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{props.workStation}</h3>
            {answeredQuestions &&
              answeredQuestions.map(function(question, index) {
                if (
                  question.QuestionResponse === "Y" ||
                  question.QuestionResponse === "N"
                ) {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <div
                        style={{
                          backgroundColor: "#E6E6E6",
                          padding: "1px"
                        }}
                      >
                        <ul>
                          {" "}
                          <b> Q :</b>
                          <div style={{ float: "right" }}>✔️</div>
                          {question.QuestionWhenAnswered}
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  );
                } else if (question.QuestionResponse === "P") {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <div
                        style={{
                          backgroundColor: "#BDBDBD",
                          padding: "1px"
                        }}
                      >
                        <ul>
                          <b> Q :</b>
                          {question.QuestionWhenAnswered}{" "}
                          <div style={{ float: "right" }}>❌</div>
                          {/* <br />
                        <b> S :</b>
                        {question.SuggestedSoloution} */}
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  );
                }
              })}
          </Modal>
        </div>
      </>
    </>
  );
}
```

this is my questions component

```
class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(props);
    this.state = {
      ...props,
      questionsAccepted: [],
      questionsAcceptedCounter: "",
      selectedSet: [],
      ViewActivityToken: false,
      noteToBeAdded: "",
      notesFromDB: [],
      addNoteToken: false,
      answeredQuestions: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.ViewActivity) {
      if (!this.state.viewDetails && !this.state.ViewActivityToken) {
        console.log(moment.locale());
        return (
          <div>
            <ModalCompletedQuestions
              RUId={this.props.RUId}
              workStation={this.props.workStation}
              WSAId={this.props.WSAId}
            />

            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: "/admin-view-full-user-wsa-responses",
                state: {
                  WSAId: this.props.WSAId
                }
              }}
            >
              <button style={{ float: "right" }} className="btn btn-primary">
                View Full Details
              </button>
            </Link>

            <br />

            <li>
              <b>User Id: </b>
              {this.props.RUId}
            </li>
            <li>
              <b>Workstation: </b>
              {this.props.workStation}
            </li>
            <li>
              <b>Date: </b>

              {moment(this.props.date).format("L")}
            </li>
            <li>
              <b>Complete Token: </b>
              {this.props.completeToken}
            </li>
          </div>
        );
      } else if (this.state.viewDetails && !this.state.ViewActivityToken) {
        return (
          <div>
            <button
              style={{ float: "right" }}
              onClick={e =>
                this.setState({
                  ViewActivity: false,
                  viewDetails: false,
                  ViewActivityToken: false,
                  addNoteToken: false
                })
              }
              className="btn btn-secondary"
            >
              Revert
            </button>
            <br />
            <br />

            {this.state.selectedSet &&
              this.state.selectedSet.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <li>
                      {" "}
                      <b>{item.QuestionWhenAnswered}</b>{" "}
                    </li>
                    <li>{item.QuestionResponse}</li>
                    <li>{item.Accepted}</li>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        );
      }
    } else if (this.state.ViewActivity && !this.state.addNoteToken) {
      return (
        <>
          <button
            style={{ float: "right" }}
            onClick={e =>
              this.setState({
                ViewActivity: false,
                viewDetails: false,
                ViewActivityToken: false,
                addNoteToken: false
              })
            }
            className="btn btn-secondary"
          >
            Revert
          </button>
          <br />
          <li>
            <b>User Id: </b>
            {this.props.RUId}
          </li>
          <li>
            <b>Workstation: </b>
            {this.props.workStation}
          </li>
          <li>
            <b>Date: </b>
            {moment(this.props.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
          </li>
          <li>
            <b>Complete Token: </b>
            {this.props.completeToken}
          </li>

          {this.state.notesFromDB &&
            this.state.notesFromDB.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                    border: "inset",
                    borderWidth: "0.2px"
                  }}
                >
                  <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
                    {moment(item.CreationTime).format("HH:MM  DD/MM/YYYY ")}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <b>{`${item.UserStatus} `}</b>
                  </div>

                  <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>{item.Notes}</div>
                </div>
              );
            })}

          <br />
          <button
            onClick={this.AddNoteBtn}
            className="btn btn-primary"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          >
            Add Note
          </button>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

How come when the first is clicked the modal appears blank but the rest of the modals are filled with the right data.

Essentially it seems as if though the first modal is not performing the data fetch which is within the modal component.

Any extra information needed let me know but these seem to be the most important for this use case.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I completed this by using a condition within the use effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoadingToken(true);
    let data = {
      WSAId: props.WSAId
    };
    fetch("/get-completed-questions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        setAnsweredQuestions(results.recordset);
      });
  }, [PUT YOUR CONDTION HERE]);
```

I simply just passed my props through so it says every time there is a new props do this.